# How to replace a text in regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
String a = "1+2cos(3)+2tan(4)+ln(3)";
String b = a.replaceAll("\) *(\w+)","*");
```

I want my string to be like

```
String a = "1+2*cos(3)+2*tan(4)+ln(3)" ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
    String a = "1+2cos(3)+2tan(4)+ln(3)";
    String b = "1+cos(3)+2tan(5)";
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll("(\\d+)(cos|tan)","$1*$2"));
    System.out.println(b.replaceAll("(\\d+)(cos|tan)","$1*$2"));
```

Yields:

```
    1+2*cos(3)+2*tan(4)+ln(3)
    1+cos(3)+2*tan(5)
```

The above will match any number which is succeeded by the words `cos` or `tan` and place it in a group. It then looks for the words `cos` or `tan` (`cos|tan`) and place them in a group (denoted by the round brackets). Once that is done, it will replace all the instances of numbers followed by `cos` and `tan` with the numbers it matched, followed by `*`, followed by whatever items it matched.

Comment: This will replace `1+cos` by `1+*cos`

Comment: @M42: Yes you are right, was fixing it. It should hold now.

Comment: @user3044181: Please use the updated version since it caters for the pitfal which M42 pointed out.

Comment: @npinti yes i did use it and it resolved my problem many thanks to you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
String b = a.replaceAll("(\d)([a-zA-Z])","$1*$2");
```

The above will look for a digit next to a alphabet, then using capture groups will insert a `*` in between the two.

Comment: but keep in mind that this won't fix the (a)(b) to a*b (not relevant for the concrete case)

Comment: it is replacing it but if i have a String a = "1+2*cos(32)+2*tan(40)+ln(3)"; it replaces String a = "1+2*cos(3*2)+2*tan(4*0)+ln(3)"; ??

Comment: @user3044181 modified the above regex a bit. Now looking for alphabets instead of `\w` earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the positive [lookbehinds and lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String b = a.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9]+)(?=[a-z]+)", "*");
```

Translation from Regex into English: insert `*` at any position in the string that is preceded by the digits and followed by the letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String string1 = "1+2cos(30)+2tan(4)+ln(39)";
string1 = string1.replaceAll("([0-9]+)(cos|sin|tan|cot|ln|log)", "$1*$2");
System.out.println(string1);
```